# Error appear every time running vim

Tags: python, vim, configuration, powerline

I am now trying to configure VIM to support Python using git bash in Windows 7. I am following the configuration step as [this website](http://realpython.com/blog/python/vim-and-python-a-match-made-in-heaven/).
However, every time i run vim from git bash, it show the following error:

```
$ vim
You need vim compiled with Python 2.6, 2.7 or 3.2 and later support
for Powerline to work. Please consult the documentation for more
details.
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I search online and find out the possible problems are the vim not able to find the shared libraries or the Python is not same as VIM support. However, i still not quite able to fix it. I have both Python 2.7 and 3.6 installed. Previously, i am having issue that python27.dll is not found in VIM through cmd, i copy the python27.dll into vim directory but it is not working as well.

This is my Python version

```
$ python --version
Python 3.6.3
```

And this is my VIM version

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Nov 17 2017 08:39:44)
Included patches: 1-1305
Compiled by <alexpux@gmail.com>
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +tag_binary
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
-autoservername  +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tcl
-balloon_eval    +folding         +mouse_xterm     +termguicolors
-browse          -footer          +multi_byte      +terminal
++builtin_terms  +fork()          +multi_lang      +terminfo
+byte_offset     +gettext         -mzscheme        +termresponse
+channel         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +textobjects
+cindent         +iconv           +num64           +timers
-clientserver    +insert_expand   +packages        +title
+clipboard       +job             +path_extra      -toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +jumplist        +perl/dyn        +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +keymap          +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +lambda          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python/dyn      +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      +python3/dyn     +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            +ruby/dyn        +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -X11
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xim
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      +startuptime     -xpm
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      -xsmp
+ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    -xterm_clipboard
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax          -xterm_save
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/etc"
 f-b for $VIMRUNTIME: "/usr/share/vim/vim80"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -I/usr/inc                                                                                                                lude/ncursesw  -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTI                                                                                                                FY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -L. -pipe -fstack-protector -pipe -Wl,--as-needed -o vim.exe                                                                                                                        -lm    -lncursesw -liconv -lacl -lintl   -Wl,--enable-auto-import -Wl,--expor                                                                                                                t-all-symbols -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base -fstack-protector-strong  -L/usr/lib/                                                                                                                perl5/core_perl/CORE -lperl -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt
```

Would appreciate if anyone can kindly explain. Thank you.

Comment: Please run the folloing command in vim `:py import sys; print(sys.version)` and show us the version. Also `:py3 import sys; print(sys.version)`.

Comment: I get error when running the command on git bash :py import sys; print(sys.version) E370: Could not load library msys-python2.7.dll E263: Sorry, this command is disabled, the Python library could not be loaded. When run py3 in git bash, i get E370: Could not load library msys-python3.6m.dll. When i run the command in cmd. it show the version 2.7.14. and for py3 show 3.5.4

Comment: Is it possible that i download the vim and python for window version and it doesn't work on git bash?

Comment: It's a huge bummer to me that these "get started with Vim!" websites all list a thousand steps to get up and running. Why don't folks just start with `vimtutor` anymore and build up their own vimrc while they figure out what they want?